# Is there a way to change O365 group email address using powershell

Tags: office-365, exchange-online

My organization wants to change email address of O365 group.  I am not able to find any power shell to change email address of already created O365 group.   I tried below command but it is not working.

```
Set-unifiedgroup -identity  testo365 -primarysmtpaddress -test123O365@qqq.onmicrosoft.com
```

Can someone please provide your thoughts on this.